# Removing greater than and less than characters and number of decimals in data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having a dataframe of 2 variables

```
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(17L, 27L, 6L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 1L,4L, 17L, 28L, 28L, 12L, 21L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 21L, 30L, 1L, 8L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 8L, 23L, 15L, 23L, 25L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 28L, 10L, 1L, 30L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 28L, 28L, 13L,1L, 4L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 30L,13L, 25L, 17L, 1L, 28L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,8L, 30L, 25L, 28L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 17L, 4L,1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 30L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 15L, 21L, 10L, 21L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 30L, 15L, 25L, 6L, 17L, 25L, 15L, 8L, 18L, 22L, 14L, 22L, 28L, 30L, 3L, 30L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 10L, 26L, 26L, 18L, 26L, 30L, 29L, 18L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 29L, 18L, 16L, 27L, 24L, 14L, 26L, 5L, 22L, 28L, 22L, 11L, 9L, 26L, 30L, 18L, 28L, 16L, 26L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 28L, 5L, 18L, 9L, 26L, 24L, 27L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 26L, 29L, 5L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 18L, 27L, 9L, 18L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 29L, 26L, 22L, 26L, 20L, 24L, 14L, 7L, 16L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 11L, 20L, 29L, 16L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 7L, 24L, 18L, 11L, 11L, 24L, 24L, 7L, 11L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 16L, 29L, 7L, 30L, 24L, 22L, 24L, 18L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 24L, 29L, 9L, 24L, 30L, 11L, 24L, 16L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 30L, 26L, 16L, 26L, 24L, 29L, 20L, 24L, 14L, 9L, 7L, 29L, 29L, 15L, 6L, 15L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 17L, 30L, 27L, 23L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 21L, 28L, 23L, 25L, 1L, 25L, 19L, 27L, 23L, 15L, 19L, 19L, 23L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 23L, 6L, 2L, 15L, 13L,1L, 1L, 13L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 21L, 1L, 28L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L,25L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 25L, 28L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 28L, 21L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 28L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 17L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 17L, 21L),
                              .Label = c("<8", ">1024", "1024", "11", "11.000000000000007", "128", "128.00000000000009", "16", "16.000000000000007", "181", "181.00000000000006", "22", "23", "23.000000000000011", "256", "256.00000000000017", "32", "32.000000000000014", "362", "362.00000000000017", "45", "45.000000000000014", "512", "512.00000000000045", "64", "64.000000000000028", "724", "8", "8.0000000000000018", "90"),
                              class = "factor"),
               X2 = structure(c(7L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 18L, 4L, 13L, 18L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L,16L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 12L,2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 2L, 16L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 16L, 7L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 13L,16L, 7L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 18L, 4L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 9L, 17L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 18L, 12L, 18L, 13L, 9L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 1L,1L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 18L, 2L, 18L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 18L, 9L, 18L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 16L, 2L, 12L,7L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 17L, 2L, 18L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 12L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 18L, 13L, 2L, 16L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 18L, 2L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L,16L, 2L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 16L, 15L, 7L, 16L, 18L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 12L,18L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 16L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 8L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 18L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 17L,13L, 18L, 7L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 7L),
                              .Label = c("<8", ">1024", "1024", "11", "128", "16", "181", "22", "23", "256", "32", "362", "45", "512", "64", "724", "8", "90"), class = "factor")),
                              .Names = c("X1", "X2"), 
                              row.names = c(NA, -471L),
                              class = "data.frame")
```

I have 2 questions

1) Each one is having some  greater than values and some with less than values. i want to remove the `>` and `<` characters from data frame and retain only the number in the dataframe. I can do it in excel but i want to learn the code for learning it in R.

2) I want to reduce the number of decimals to integer/whole number as some are having more number of decimals.

It may be a small question, but i am struggling to do this. i highly appreciate for this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with base R:

```
my_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(my_df, gsub, pattern = "<|>", replacement = ""))
my_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(my_df, as.numeric))

my_df
#                    X1   X2
# 1                   8   23
# 2                   8   90
# 3                   8    8
# 4                   8  362
# 5                   8   45
# 6                  90  362
# 7                 256  724
# 8                  64  181
# 9                 128  362
# 10                 32  181
# 11                 64  724
# 12                256 1024
# 13                 16  362
# 14 32.000000000000014  181
# 15 45.000000000000014  724
# 16 23.000000000000011  362
# 17 45.000000000000014  724
# 18                  8 1024
# 19                 90  362
# 20               1024 1024
# 21                 90   64
# 22 23.000000000000011  181
# 23 32.000000000000014  181
# 24 45.000000000000014 1024
# 25 512.00000000000045  181
```

If you  only want to round the decimals, but keep the < and > signs you can do the following (without perfoming the steps above):

```
sapply(my_df, 
       function(x) paste0(gsub(x, pattern = "\\d|\\.", replacement = ""), 
                          round(as.numeric(gsub(x, pattern = "<|>", replacement = "")))))

#      X1     X2     
# [1,] "<8"   "23"   
# [2,] "<8"   "90"   
# [3,] "8"    "<8"   
# [4,] "8"    "362"  
# [5,] "<8"   "45"   
# [6,] "90"   "362"  
# [7,] "256"  "724"  
# [8,] "64"   "181"  
# [9,] "128"  "362"  
# [10,] "32"   "181"  
# [11,] "64"   "724"  
# [12,] "256"  ">1024"
# [13,] "16"   "362"  
# [14,] "32"   "181"  
# [15,] "45"   "724"  
# [16,] "23"   "362"  
# [17,] "45"   "724"  
# [18,] "8"    ">1024"
# [19,] "90"   "362"  
# [20,] "1024" ">1024"
# [21,] "90"   "64"   
# [22,] "23"   "181"  
# [23,] "32"   "181"  
# [24,] "45"   ">1024"
# [25,] "512"  "181"
```

**How it works**

`sapply` takes the `data.frame` and applys the function specified after the comma to each column of the `data.frame`. `gsub` substitute the pattern with the replacement in `x` (a column of the `data.frame`). There I used regular expression, so `\\d` means all digits (0-9) and `\\.` the dot and `|` combines them with a OR logic.

**stringr-solution**

There's a shorter solution with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(my_df, 
       function(x) str_c(str_extract(x, "[<>]?"), 
                         round(as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d+")))))
```

Here the pattern we want to have are extracted and then combined again after rounding the decimals.

**Data**

```
my_df <- 
  structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 30L, 15L, 
                                  25L, 6L, 17L, 25L, 15L, 8L, 18L, 
                                  22L, 14L, 22L, 28L, 30L, 3L, 30L, 
                                  14L, 18L, 22L, 24L), 
                                .Label = c("<8", ">1024", "1024", "11", 
                                           "11.000000000000007", "128", 
                                           "128.00000000000009", "16", 
                                           "16.000000000000007", "181", 
                                           "181.00000000000006", "22", 
                                           "23", "23.000000000000011", 
                                           "256", "256.00000000000017", 
                                           "32", "32.000000000000014", 
                                           "362", "362.00000000000017", 
                                           "45", "45.000000000000014", 
                                           "512", "512.00000000000045", 
                                           "64", "64.000000000000028", 
                                           "724", "8", 
                                           "8.0000000000000018", "90"), 
                                class = "factor"), 
                 X2 = structure(c(9L, 18L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 7L, 
                                  12L, 7L, 16L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 
                                  16L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L), 
                                .Label = c("<8", ">1024", "1024", "11", 
                                           "128", "16", "181", "22", "23", 
                                           "256", "32", "362", "45", "512", 
                                           "64", "724", "8", "90"), 
                                class = "factor")), 
            .Names = c("X1", "X2"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -25L), 
            class = "data.frame")

#                    X1    X2
# 1                  <8    23
# 2                  <8    90
# 3                   8    <8
# 4                   8   362
# 5                  <8    45
# 6                  90   362
# 7                 256   724
# 8                  64   181
# 9                 128   362
# 10                 32   181
# 11                 64   724
# 12                256 >1024
# 13                 16   362
# 14 32.000000000000014   181
# 15 45.000000000000014   724
# 16 23.000000000000011   362
# 17 45.000000000000014   724
# 18                  8 >1024
# 19                 90   362
# 20               1024 >1024
# 21                 90    64
# 22 23.000000000000011   181
# 23 32.000000000000014   181
# 24 45.000000000000014 >1024
# 25 512.00000000000045   181
```

Comment: yes this to answered my both the questions. thank you very much

Comment: can you explain how to get rid of the decimals, but keeping the characters?

Comment: You mean how to only keep > and <?

Comment: I want to keep all the <8 values, > 1024 values, intermediates except that those with high decimals i want to make it to a whole number. thanking you.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the answer

Comment: even after converting it into a number by as.numeric, it still shows as factor only. how to convert this as numeric. I checked with str(df) command

Comment: For me it is converted to numeric column. You might want to ask a new question with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use `dplyr::mutate_all` and  `stringr::str_replace_all`.
2. Decimals are directly approximated by `as.numeric` since it is ~`10^(-13)`magnitude.

```r
your_df <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(17L, 27L, 6L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 1L,4L, 17L, 28L, 28L, 12L, 21L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 21L, 30L, 1L, 8L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 8L, 23L, 15L, 23L, 25L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 28L, 10L, 1L, 30L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 28L, 28L, 13L,1L, 4L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 30L,13L, 25L, 17L, 1L, 28L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,8L, 30L, 25L, 28L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 17L, 4L,1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 30L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 15L, 21L, 10L, 21L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 30L, 15L, 25L, 6L, 17L, 25L, 15L, 8L, 18L, 22L, 14L, 22L, 28L, 30L, 3L, 30L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 10L, 26L, 26L, 18L, 26L, 30L, 29L, 18L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 29L, 18L, 16L, 27L, 24L, 14L, 26L, 5L, 22L, 28L, 22L, 11L, 9L, 26L, 30L, 18L, 28L, 16L, 26L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 28L, 5L, 18L, 9L, 26L, 24L, 27L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 26L, 29L, 5L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 18L, 27L, 9L, 18L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 29L, 26L, 22L, 26L, 20L, 24L, 14L, 7L, 16L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 11L, 20L, 29L, 16L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 7L, 24L, 18L, 11L, 11L, 24L, 24L, 7L, 11L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 16L, 29L, 7L, 30L, 24L, 22L, 24L, 18L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 24L, 29L, 9L, 24L, 30L, 11L, 24L, 16L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 30L, 26L, 16L, 26L, 24L, 29L, 20L, 24L, 14L, 9L, 7L, 29L, 29L, 15L, 6L, 15L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 17L, 30L, 27L, 23L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 21L, 28L, 23L, 25L, 1L, 25L, 19L, 27L, 23L, 15L, 19L, 19L, 23L, 2L, 27L, 27L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 23L, 6L, 2L, 15L, 13L,1L, 1L, 13L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 21L, 1L, 28L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L,25L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 25L, 28L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 28L, 21L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 28L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 17L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 17L, 21L), .Label = c("<8", ">1024", "1024", "11", "11.000000000000007", "128", "128.00000000000009", "16", "16.000000000000007", "181", "181.00000000000006", "22", "23", "23.000000000000011", "256", "256.00000000000017", "32", "32.000000000000014", "362", "362.00000000000017", "45", "45.000000000000014", "512", "512.00000000000045", "64", "64.000000000000028", "724", "8", "8.0000000000000018", "90"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(7L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 18L, 4L, 13L, 18L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L,16L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 12L,2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 2L, 16L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 16L, 7L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 13L,16L, 7L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 18L, 4L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 9L, 17L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 18L, 12L, 18L, 13L, 9L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 1L,1L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 18L, 2L, 18L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 18L, 9L, 18L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                12L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 16L, 2L, 12L,7L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 17L, 2L, 18L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 12L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 18L, 13L, 2L, 16L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 18L, 2L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 2L,16L, 2L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 16L, 15L, 7L, 16L, 18L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 12L,18L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 16L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 8L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 18L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 17L,13L, 18L, 7L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 7L), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              .Label = c("<8", ">1024", "1024", "11", "128", "16", "181", "22", "23", "256", "32", "362", "45", "512", "64", "724", "8", "90"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -471L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mutate_all(your_df, function(x) as.numeric(str_replace_all(x, pattern = "<|>", replacement = "")))

#>       X1   X2
#> 1     32  181
#> 2    724 1024
#> 3    128 1024
#> 4      8   22
#> 5      8   90
#> 6      8   11
#> 7      8   45
#> 8     11   90
#> 9     32   22
#> 10     8   45
#> 11     8   22
#> 12    22   90
#> 13    45  362
```

Comment: Thank you very much as it answered both of my question